# running JavaScript function on url? google.com?javascript:(func())

Tags: javascript, function, url

I would like to run javascript function after link load. 
Link is for example google and I would like to run function after load, without pressing any bookmarks etc. Is it possible to make a link like

`http://google.com?javascript:(function(){}(something here);)`

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible, because if it were, then [XSS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) would potentially be around the corner of every link.

Comment: I was wondering that would be the case. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, URLs just don't support this.  There are [bookmarklets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) the user can use once the page loads, but nothing you can automatically run as part of a URL.

Answer (score 0):

That is impossible. You cannot control the code on other pages (this would be a huge security problem).

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else has noted, you cannot run a Javascript function that way.

What is it that you're hoping to accomplish with your javascript?  Perhaps there is another way to achieve your end result?